# How to map dict into another dict Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict of the following pairs:

```
{0: Account(13, 1), 1: Account(15, 5), 2: Account(55, 1), 3: Account(33 ,1)}
```

I would like to remap it and get the following dict

```
{second_value_of_dict1: list[index_of_dict1]}
```

Example:

```
{1: [0, 2, 3], 5: [1]}
```

Comment: Can you explain what "second value of dict1" means?  Dictionaries are unordered, so it's not clear what the second value would be.

Comment: (1.) There is no natural way to "map a dict into another dict". There are only algorithms for transforming data, so you have to provide/propose one. (2.) Your proposed algorithm is entirely unclear to at least me from this example.

Comment: We don't know what `Account` is, even, so can't tell you how to get the second value you pass when creating it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Your edit erased information that explained (however subtlely) the intent. The keys of the new dictionary are the italicized second elements of the values of the first dictionary.

Comment: @chepner I don't think that was my edit; blame Two-Bit Alchemist!

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It was indeed Two-Bit Alchemist!

Comment: Just to be clear, I know how to do it with a loop and if statements, but I am looking for a more elegant python solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `defaultdict` as follow:

```
class Account:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

d_in = {0: Account(13, 1), 1: Account(15, 5), 2: Account(55, 1), 3: Account(33 ,1)} 
d_out = collections.defaultdict(list)

for index, k in enumerate(d_in.keys()):
    d_out[d_in[k].y].append(index)

print d_out
```

Giving the following output:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: [0, 2, 3], 5: [1]})
```

If you really want it to look like a regular `dict` then:

```
print dict(d_out)
```

Giving:

```
{1: [0, 2, 3], 5: [1]}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Account:
    def __init__(self, p1, p2):
        self.p1 = p1
        self.p2 = p2

dict1 = {0: Account(13,1), 1: Account(15,5), 2: Account(55,1), 3: Account(33,1)}
dict2 = {}
for key, val in dict1.iteritems():
    if val.p2 not in dict2:
        dict2[val.p2] = []
    dict2[val.p2].append(key)
print dict2
```

Comment: You could use `defaultdict` or `dict.setdefault` here